# How do I set up my POE::Filter to receive the entire chunk of data returned from the server?

Tags: perl, poe

I tried the following

```
my $filter = POE::Filter::Line->new(OutputLiteral => '');

my $wheel = POE::Wheel::ReadWrite->new(
    Handle       => $socket,
    Filter       => $filter,
    InputEvent   => 'on_input',
    ErrorEvent   => 'on_error',
    FlushedEvent => 'on_flush',
);
```

But on_input is called several times with each line separately in ARG0. How do I get it all together? Doesn't setting setting OutputLiteral to '' change the filter's understanding of what a "line" is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are reading from the filter, so it's `InputLiteral` which is important here, not `OutputLiteral.` Second, you can't have an empty `InputLiteral` (if you try, it will just autodetect the input literal). Consequently, you can't use `POE::Filter::Line` to get all the data, because it is made for parsing line-terminated records. Use `POE::Filter::Stream` instead.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about POE::Filter::Stream. I thought I checked out all the POE::Filter:: modules already:/. Thanks for the answer.